# как можно исправить float: right для адаптивного дизайна

Tags: javascript, css, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Возник такой вопрос, кто-то ужасно кодил, что написал футер с обратной стороны, чтобы использовать `float: right`. Мне необходимо, чтобы в конечной версии он был корректный и начинался с тега **Главная** ну и т. д. для адаптивного дизайна.

И еще момент, к сожалению зайти просто в html код не получится, так как он тянется с БД, мне сказали, html трогать нельзя, чтобы стили не слетели.

Что использовать, может есть свойство CSS который мне поможет, или прописать JS?

Вот собственно и HTML код:

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer_inner">
    <div id="left_foot">
      <a href="/" id="logo2"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_foot">
      <div class="moduletable">
        <ul class="nav menu">
          <li class="item-109 current active"><a href="/kontaktnaya-informatsiya.html">Контакты</a></li>
          <li class="item-112"><a href="/dostavka.html">Доставка и установка</a></li>
          <li class="item-111"><a href="/oplata.html">Оплата</a></li>
          <li class="item-110"><a href="/o-magazine.html">О магазине</a></li>
          <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      Алматы, ул. Бокейханова, 49, офис 1 <a class="map" href>Мы на карте Алматы</a>
      <div class="tel_b"><span>+7 (727)</span> 386-30-87</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="underfoot">
  <div id="uf_middle">
    <div id="uf_left">2016 © DveriCity.kz | <a href="http://dveri-city.kz" title="Купить двери в Алматы на заказ">Купить двери в Алматы на заказ</a>.</div>
    <div id="uf_right">Создание сайта
      <noindex><a rel="nofollow" class="reffirm" href="http://okit.kz">okit.kz</a></noindex>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот что получилось исходя из этого кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Данную проблему можно решить при помощи простого CSS, изменяющего отображаемый порядок списка путем двойного переворота на 180 градусов.

```
ul {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul > li {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/n6uhdLhw/

Comment: Уверены, что надо по-прежнему использовать префикс `-moz`?

Comment: Пусть будет, для старых браузеров. Так надежнее. Приятней, конечно, когда все это расставляет autoprefixer, но тут речь не об этом.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием `display: flex`:

```css
.nav.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer_inner">
    <div id="left_foot">
        <a href="/" id="logo2"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_foot">
        <div class="moduletable">
            <ul class="nav menu">
                <li class="item-109 current active"><a href="/kontaktnaya-informatsiya.html">Контакты</a></li>
                <li class="item-112"><a href="/dostavka.html">Доставка и установка</a></li>
                <li class="item-111"><a href="/oplata.html">Оплата</a></li>
                <li class="item-110"><a href="/o-magazine.html">О магазине</a></li>
                <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        Алматы, ул. Бокейханова, 49, офис 1 <a class="map" href>Мы на карте Алматы</a>
        <div class="tel_b"><span>+7 (727)</span> 386-30-87</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с использованием jQuery:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    var container = $('#right_foot .nav.menu');
    container.children().each(function() {
      container.prepend(this);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer_inner">
    <div id="left_foot">
        <a href="/" id="logo2"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_foot">
        <div class="moduletable">
            <ul class="nav menu">
                <li class="item-109 current active"><a href="/kontaktnaya-informatsiya.html">Контакты</a></li>
                <li class="item-112"><a href="/dostavka.html">Доставка и установка</a></li>
                <li class="item-111"><a href="/oplata.html">Оплата</a></li>
                <li class="item-110"><a href="/o-magazine.html">О магазине</a></li>
                <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        Алматы, ул. Бокейханова, 49, офис 1 <a class="map" href>Мы на карте Алматы</a>
        <div class="tel_b"><span>+7 (727)</span> 386-30-87</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А еще лучше `flex-direction: column-reverse`.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, спасибо.

Comment: Не за что, только свойство `flex-flow` лучше все-таки выпилить, потому что `flex-direction` его переопределяет.